# While loop with iteration

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I am trying to create a while loop where the user has a total of three tries to enter a valid number. I'm not understanding how the system recognizes that 3 invalid attempts have been made before displaying the message.
Classes, variables, and scanner objects are made. After the three attempts, I want to say "No more tries". I already have the program written to use the user's input for quantity if its valid. This is just if they input three invalid attempts.

```
Updated code:
```

int quantity = 0;

```
        // Get user's desired amount of lemonade cups
        System.out.print("Hello " + name + ". How many cups of lemonade can I get you? ");
        quantity = keyboard.nextInt(); // Store amount of cups wanted

        int attempts = 0;
        int maxAttempts = 3;
        double subTotal = quantity * lemonadeCost;
        double totalTax = subTotal * 0.08;
        double totalPrice = subTotal + totalTax;

        while (attempts < maxAttempts) {
            if (quantity < 1 || quantity >= 20) {
                System.out.println("That is an invalid amount, please try again");
                quantity = keyboard.nextInt(); }

             else {
                 System.out.println("Subtotal: " + defaultFormat.format(subTotal));
                 System.out.println("Tax: " + defaultFormat.format(totalTax));
                 System.out.println("Total: " + defaultFormat.format(totalPrice)); 

            }
             attempts++;
                if (attempts >= 3) {
                    System.out.print ("No lemonade for you");
                    break;
                }
            // Ask for user's payment method
            Scanner method = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("How would you like to pay? Enter 'm'   for money, 'c' for credit or 'g' for gold. ");
            String payment = method.nextLine();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone. I modeled my code after CodeRunner's example. It seemed most simple and appropriate for what I was asked to do. This is what I have for my code, however it's not working as intended. After the second invalid attempt, it will just ask the user how they want to pay. If I select a valid number, the receipt will be printed nonstop. Also, should the pay method be within the else statement?

Comment: So I removed continue; and it stopped printing nonstop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[dxdy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5390857/dxdy) is correct about the braces required for making the while() loop function.

Once the while loop has ended (either quantity is between 1 and 20, or attempts > maxAttempts), you just need to have an if statement like the following:

```
if (attempts > maxAttempts) {
  System.out.println("No more tries);
  return -1; // or something else to break out of your code
}
```

and then continue on with the rest of your code working with the quantity variable.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing the opening and closing brackets for the loop. As it is, your code reads

```
while (quantity < 1 || quantity >= 20 && attempts <= maxAttempts)
   System.out.println("That is an invalid amount, please try again"); 
// these below are not part of the loop
quantity = keyboard.nextInt();
attempts++;
```

Instead you should do

```
while (quantity < 1 || quantity >= 20 && attempts <= maxAttempts){
   System.out.println("That is an invalid amount, please try again"); 
   quantity = keyboard.nextInt();
   attempts++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** As you updated the question, so it was necessary to update the answer too. Here it is what you actually want.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Get user's desired amount of lemonade cups
    String name = "Jimmy Nguyen";
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int quantity;// Store amount of cups wanted
    int lemonadeCost = 4; // Suppose
    int attempts = 0;
    int maxAttempts = 3;
    System.out.print("Hello " + name + ". How many cups of lemonade can I get you? ");
    while (attempts < maxAttempts) {

        quantity = keyboard.nextInt();
        if (quantity < 1 || quantity >= 20) {
            System.out.println("That is an invalid amount, please try again\n");
            ++attempts;
        } else {
            double subTotal = quantity * lemonadeCost;
            double totalTax = subTotal * 0.08;
            double totalPrice = subTotal + totalTax;
            System.out.println("Subtotal: " + subTotal);
            System.out.println("Tax: " + totalTax);
            System.out.println("Total: " + totalPrice);
            // Ask for user's payment method
            System.out.println("How would you like to pay? Enter 'm'   for money, 'c' for credit or 'g' for gold. ");
            keyboard.nextLine();
            String payment = keyboard.nextLine();
            break;
        }

        if (attempts >= 3) {
            System.out.print("No lemonade for you");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey! I cleaned up my code with your help. I was able to run your program successfully, but ran into trouble when trying to add it into my own. If you have another minute to take a look, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Put all the above code inside main method. Hey! What it that trouble?

Comment: The issue now is that my code doesn't wait for three invalid tries before displaying the message. On top of that, it displays the wrong message. It goes straight to how the user would like to pay.

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
        //start with 1 since the user will attempt it at least one time.
        int attempts = 1;

        int maxAttempts = 3;

        int quantity=0;

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        //LESS THAN OR EQUAL TO 3... 
        while(attempts<=maxAttempts){

            System.out.print("Enter amount: ");

            quantity = keyboard.nextInt();

            //check if valid

            if(quantity < 1 || quantity >= 20){


                //check if it's 1st and 2nd trial.
                if(attempts<maxAttempts){

                    System.out.println("That is an invalid amount, please try again");

                }else{
                    //third trial and still invalid
                    System.out.print("No more tries");

                }

            }else{

                //user entered a valid amount so let's break the loops. 
                System.out.println("The amount is valid. Value of amount: "+ quantity);
                break;
            }
            //increment attempts
            attempts++;
        }

        //never forget to close the scanner
        keyboard.close();
    }
}
```

Though I could have turned this into methods if it's allowed

Comment: Yeah. My instructor doesn't want us to incorporate methods yet. This really helps, thank you. The double stage of if and else is new to me. I usually thought an else statement should fall after the if. Didn't know that we can put double ifs and double else.

Comment: You can have if statement inside another if statement.. It's called "nested if". You can read more about it here(https://www.cs.umd.edu/~clin/MoreJava/ControlFlow/nested-if.html)